# PyQt5 GUI crashes when QDialog from different module is closed

Tags: python, pyqt5, crash

I made a helper window with PyQt5 to load some data in it's own module and when used in a simple scripts it works. Here is the important parts of the code:

```
def read_dialog():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = HelperWindow()
    status = window.exec()
    if status == 0:
        data = window.get_data()
    elif status == 1:
        print('Warning: Dialog rejected. Returning empty list.')
        data = []

    return data


class HelperWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        # code to set up the UI

    def load_button_clicked(self):
        self.done(0)
    
    def get_data(self):
        data = []
        # do some stuff
        return data
```

My other script is importing these functions and looks like this:

```
from utils import read_dialog

class mainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # code to set up a layout
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.show()

    def load_data(self):
        data = read_dialog()
        if data != []:
            self.do_something_with_data(data)

    def do_something_with_data(self, data):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = mainWindow()
    app.exec()
```

The code crashes without any errormessage if I hit the load button, even in debug mode (PyCharm CE 2023). However if I set a breakpoint at the line `return data` in the function `read_dialog`, and then resume to the code it does not crash.

Does it have to do with the `window.get_data()` being called and then trying returning the data before it has finished? I read something that in PyQt having multiple threads that are not spawned by the main program can cause problems, so I am wondering if QDialog is opening a new thread here.

Comment: Update: The breakpoint trick seemed to work only once. Sometimes the breakpoint is not even reached.

Comment: as form using two `exec()` (and two `QApplications`) can be wrong idea. When it finishs one `exec()` then it may remove all information from memory and it may crush other `exec()`. As for me every GUI (in any module - like `PyQt`, `tkinter`, `wxPython`, `PyGTK`) should run only one `exec()`

Comment: I'm not sure it is good idea to use `windows` after finishing `exec()` because after finishing `exec()` it may remove all class from memory and it may have no access to `window.get_data()`. If you close dialog using some button then you could run `get_data()` in function assigned to button and assign it to external variable - before it will run `exec()`.

Comment: Qt only allows **one** application object to be created. So always use `if QApplication.instance() is None: app = QApplication(sys.argv)`.

Comment: @furas In cases like these, the normal assumption is that the deletion of the Qt object relies on Python garbage collection, which will eventually delete the Qt object if no parent was given (but that's not 100% sure, as it may depend on lots of aspects). This means that, within the same function call, the QDialog still exists unless it's been instantly destroyed for some reason (such as using `WA_DeleteOnClose`) because control has not returned to the event loop yet, which otherwise destroys it *lazily*.

Comment: Remember that most IDEs don't show the full traceback, especially when dealing with bindings that use non-python libraries like Qt. In these cases (and as a good practice anyway), always remember to try to run your code in a terminal or prompt, *even if it works*. Still, the fact remains: as said above, you can only have *one* QApplication (or QGuiApplication/QCoreApplication), and trying to create/start another one is just pointless, other than wrong.

Comment: Thanks @ekhumoro now it works fine. I did not now that only one QApplication is allowed.